# jQuery - can $.json have to a call another page or can it use a query already run on the current page?

Tags: jquery, getjson

**Nothing is currently broken.    :)  I'm just looking to gain some performance.**

I have a form with chained select (one drop down changes, and the second drop down value changes).  Right now, my form will perform an ajax call to another page and retrieve the contents as json data string.  This is fast but if the data was already retrieved (e.g. stored in memory), the changes would be instantaneous instead of the slight delay.  Can I change the call this function to something that runs within the page?  For example, [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/default.html)  does this (look at the source code).  Right now, when you change the value for the operating system, the list of models will change.  If i loaded the modele in memory, I'd need to model the json string to include which options corresponded to the operating systems.

To put it in other words, can I create the json string and store it in memory and then just reference this data instead of making a separate ajax call?

```
function updateModels(i){
    var pltfrm = $(i).val();
    var firstOption = $(i);
    var model = firstOption.parent().next().find('.model');
    $.getJSON("index.cfm?do=misc.getModels&platform=" + pltfrm,
    function(j){
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) 
        {
            options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
        }
    model.html(options);
    });
}
```

My json data is curently formatted for the LINUX OS:

```
[
{"optionValue":"","optionDisplay":"Select a model"},
{"optionValue":"Dell 2850","optionDisplay":"Dell 2850"},
{"optionValue":"Dell 2950","optionDisplay":"Dell 2950"},
{"optionValue":"Dell 2970", "optionDisplay":"Dell 2970"},
{"optionValue":"Dell 6850", "optionDisplay":"Dell 6850"},
{"optionValue":"Dell R710", "optionDisplay":"Dell R710"}
]
```

This is **very low priority** but I know it would help performance so if you have time and are willing to work with me, I'd sure appreciate it.

Comment: Store the first Ajax call's reponse data in a variable, then when you need the data you check if that variable has a value and if so just use it directly instead of making another Ajax call. Is that what you mean? Or do you want to eliminate Ajax completely and put all the data in a variable in the initial page?

Comment: Eliminate Ajax completely and put all the data in a variable in the initial page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just save the data in the localStorage:

```
function updateModels(i){
    var pltfrm = $(i).val();
    var firstOption = $(i);
    var model = firstOption.parent().next().find('.model');

    var storedItemSerialized = localStorage.getItem('model' + pltfrm), storedItem = {};

    var redrawModels = function (j)
    {
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) 
        {
            options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
        }
        model.html(options);

    }


    if (storedItemSerialized)
    {
       redrawModels($.parseJSON(storedItemSerialized));
    }
    else
    {

      $.getJSON("index.cfm?do=misc.getModels&platform=" + pltfrm,
      function(j){
        localStorage.setItem('model' + pltfrm, JSON.stringify(j));
        redrawModels(j);
      });

    }
}
```

This method has the added benefit of saving the data through page requests.

Comment: Thought what about on browsers which don't support localStorage? You might need a shim or basic implementation using a cookie or even in-page variable instead for those browsers.

Comment: Well, localStorage has been available in IE since 8, and the rest of the pack for a long while too.  Hopefully people won't have to worry about coding for IE < 8 for too much longer.

Comment: Really? Huh, I always thought it was only in IE9 and the real browsers. Good to know.

Comment: I looked at firebug and can see the page request despite what selections where made for the platform.  I don't know how to setup a jsfiddle when an ajax page is requested.  I'll need to read up on that.  Otherwise, I've implemented this incorrectly.

Comment: what happens when you enter this into your firebug console: `localStorage.getItem('modelFOO')` where FOO is obviously a valid value for one the models you've already selected.  You should see a JSON string returned.

Comment: @JakeFeasel - I love firebug.  Looks like when I copied and pasted, I overwrite a line which messed up the syntax.  Once I corrected that, your solution worked "out of the box"  Thanks for showing me how to do this!